# Microsoft Teams Adal silent Authentication fail (iframe sandbox)

Tags: javascript, microsoft-teams, adal.js

We have developped a custom tab for Microsoft Teams and would like to authenticate users silently, using Adal as describe in this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/auth-silent-aad
It works fine in development environment, but fail in production environment !
The console show the following error message :

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with origin 'https://teams.microsoft.com' from frame with URL 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&client_id=(...) Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with origin 'https://teams.microsoft.com' from frame with URL 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&client_id=(...)'. The frame attempting navigation of the top-level window is sandboxed, but the flag of 'allow-top-navigation' or 'allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation' is not set.

I don't understand why the behavior is different in development and production environment?
How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: what do you have in your `sandbox` attribute ?

Comment: As Addeladde point it, the iframe is created by Teams : sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-pointer-lock allow-scripts allow-same-origin"

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow top navigation on your `iframe` element by providing some attribute value to the `sandbox` attribute

```
<iframe src="yourpage.html" sandbox="allow-top-navigation"></iframe>
```

Have a look at [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp) to know more about those attribute values.

Comment: the iframe is created by the Teams application is there a way for me to affect how the iframe is created?

Comment: If you can add scripts on that page, then *yes*. you can write script to get that iframe and modify it's `sandbox` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in you tab page

```js
window.onload = function () {

        if (parent.document.getElementById("extension-tab-frame")) {
            var iframe = parent.document.getElementById("extension-tab-frame");
            iframe.sandbox = 'allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-pointer-lock allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-top-navigation';
        }
    }
```

Comment: This causes a DOMException `Blocked a frame with origin "https://myoriginalpage.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`